# I cannot @putmapping spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

The @Putmapping annotation not works correcty on my code. I want to make update operation with put mapping, but its make postmapping and add a new record to database.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

update with putmapping

Comment: can you show some code please?

Comment: Spring works. The problem is elsewhere, probably in your `brandService.update()` code. Can you please show us that? If you think a PUT call is being handled by your `add()` method, please get a stronger proof, e.g. a log message.

Comment: https://github.com/abdulkadirozyurt/campspring code is here. Its include a lot of comment, cause i cannot take screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

In your service class in update method you are calling the save method.

```
@Override
    public void update(UpdateBrandRequest updateBrandRequest) {
        // jparepository brand tanıdığı için hep brand nesnesi lazım.
        
        Brand brand = this.modelMapperService.forRequest().map(updateBrandRequest, Brand.class);
        this.brandRepository.save(brand);    // updaterequest içinde id olduğu için buradaki save, update işlemi yapar.
    }
```

But before that for put mapping you need to send the Id for which you are trying to update and you have to use setters method to set the new values for that perticular record.

below I can show u the example from my code:

```
@Override
public Candy updateCandy(Candy candy, int candyId) throws CandyShopServiceException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Candy candy1 = candyRepository.findById(candyId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new CandyNotFoundException("Candy by this Id not found"));
        candy1.setCandyName(candy.getCandyName());
        candy1.setCandyStock(candy.getCandyStock());
        return candyRepository.save(candy1);
    }
```

In the above code I am passing the Candy object and perticular candy Id from the postman as a put mapping and from that Id I'm looking for the perticular candy and using setter method to set the value of new candy by replacing existing candy record.

Feel free to comment if you have any doubt in this.